# Is the file '/etc/network/interfaces' ignored when I use the Network Manager?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

I had this configuration in a server

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
   address 192.168.1.250
   network 192.168.1.0
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   broadcast 192.168.1.255
   gateway 192.168.1.1
```

`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wired-conexion`

```
[connection]
id=wired-conexion
uuid=0c501f08acc5497cb7de8c815a297537
type=8023ethernet

[8023ethernet]

[ipv4]
method=manual
dns=8.8.8.8;
dns-search=8.8.4.4;
address1=192.168.1.250/24,192.168.1.1

[ipv6]
method=auto
ip6privacy=0
```

Then I commented these lines in `/etc/network/interfaces` file

```
# auto em1
# iface em1 inet static
#    address 192.168.1.250
#    network 192.168.1.0
#    netmask 255.255.255.0
#    broadcast 192.168.1.255
#    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

I restarted the service

```
service network-manager restart
```

And I lost the communication with the server because I was remotely connected. I have a similar configuration in my  laptop and everything works well. I thought the file `/etc/network/interfaces` was ignored when I used the network-manager, is that right? If I uncomment again the lines will it work again?

**Update:** more configurations (I change manage -> true) and `/etc/network/interfaces` should be ignored

`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/conexionname`

```
[connection]
id=conexionname
uuid=8e603a9b-...
type=802-3-ethernet

[802-3-ethernet]

[ipv4]
method=manual
dns=8.8.8.8;
dns-search=8.8.4.4;
address1=192.168.1.250/24,192.168.1.1
may-fail=false

[ipv6]
method=auto
ip6-privacy=0
```

`/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Comment: Whats the output of `grep -A1 '^.ifupdown' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` ?

Comment: Changes in /etc/network/interfaces might need also restart of networking.

Comment: @heemayl the output is: `[ifupdown] managed=false`

Comment: change the line `managed=false` to `managed=true` , then restart network manager and then check..

Comment: However, if you let NM manage the interfaces listed in `/etc/network/interfaces` then why populate `interfaces` at all?? Just set your static IP in NM.

Comment: @heemayl I tried with `managed=true`, now I can access from our office, but I can't access to the server from outside. I'm going to add to the question the network configuration in the Network Manager

Comment: In the `[802-3-ethernet]` section should appear the MAC-address or am I wrong?

Comment: Well, but you were right @heemayl, if you write your comment as an answer I could mark it as correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default `ifup`/`ifdown` configures network interfaces based on interface definitions from `/etc/network/interface` file.

`network-manager` can read and configure interfaces reading this file, using a plugin named `ifupdown`.

You might see a line like in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file's `main` configuration snippet :

```
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
```

these are the plugins in use.

Next in the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file you should have :

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

This `managed=false` means `network-manager` will not manage network interfaces defined in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

To solve your problem you need to make it `true` so that the `/etc/network/interfaces` file is parsed by `network-manager` and hence the relevant interface(s) will be configured accordingly :

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

On a different note, if you have interface(s) defined in `/etc/network/interfaces` and not using `network-manager` for any other interfaces then you should better consider these two options :

- Let `ifup`/`ifdown` manages the interface(s) (you can uninstall `network-manager` if you want in this case)
- Configure interface(s) directly using `network-manager`